# How do I lay out a scoring sheet in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, grids

Think of a Yahtzee scoring sheet: slots for names along the top, scoring opportunities along the edge. Fit to the size of the page.

Google is yet again being unhelpful, thinking I want to make musical sheet music scores instead.

Is there a way to easily do this?

Comment: Sounds like a standard table should do the trick …

Comment: Since you are probably enlarging the tabular, \resizebox or \adjustbox is acceptable.